Separate ARP tables for qemu guest on wifi lan
I need a qemu vm to have a stand alone private ip on my lan. I only have a wifi physical device. NAT mode won't work as I need the guest to have it's own ARP table.
I'm seeing non-unique MACs on my wifi network and need to investigate. I've locked down my host ARP table to the known good MAC address. I want a vm to use the suspect MAC so I can investigate. I don't think I'm willing to expose my host to this device without better understanding what's going on here. The device in question is a NetGear Network extender, so it raises some red flags to me. Is there anyway to get unique lan ips(perferably through router's DHCP) for my vms AND my host all with unique MACs such that I can manipulate requests at the ARP level?
I'm running fedora 41 and libvirt.
If not clear; I need some way for my qemu guests to make requests to the suspicious device over wlan without removing the restrictions on my host machine.  I only have a single physical device, NAT mode won't work as it would use the host's arp cache to lookup the hmac of the suspicious device.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
